# Jade Android standalone execution

Tags: android, agents-jade

I want to use Jade as standalone in Android environment.

Of course I'm using JadeLeapAndroid 4.3.3

I found these posts which was very helpful,

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jade.devel/12271 
http://jade.tilab.com/pipermail/jade-develop/2013q1/018940.html

but I have a problem now.

I can bind service via this code.

[code starts here]

```
public void bind() {
    sc = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.d("SERVICE", "Bind Success");
            binder = (RuntimeServiceBinder) service;
            container();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.d("SERVICE", "Bind Fail");
            binder = null;
        }
    };

    Log.d("SERVICE", "Bind Trial");
    bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RuntimeService.class),
        sc, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

[code ends here]

But when I continues with AgentContainer with this code,

[code starts here]

```
public void container() {
    Profile profile = new ProfileImpl();

    binder.createAgentContainer(profile, new RuntimeCallback<AgentContainerHandler>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AgentContainerHandler agentContainerHandler) {
            try {
                Log.d("CONTAINER", "Startup Success");
                ContainerController cc = agentContainerHandler.getAgentContainer();
                //AgentController ac = cc.getAgent("Arin");
                AgentController ac = cc.createNewAgent("TestAgent", TestAgent.class.getName(),
                        new Object[] { new Object() });
                ac.start();
                //agent(agentContainerHandler);
            } catch (ControllerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("CONTAINER", "Startup Fail");
        }
    });
}
```

[code ends here]

it shows error on FileNotFound (EROFS) exception.

(It occurs even I deleted all codes in onSuccess method)

[error starts here]

```
06-23 01:24:26.423  25603-25627/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid     E/jade.core.messaging.Messaging﹕ Error writing platform address
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: MTPs-Main-Container.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:80)
        at jade.core.messaging.MessagingService.boot(MessagingService.java:326)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.bootAllServices(AgentContainerImpl.java:468)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.startNode(AgentContainerImpl.java:408)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:495)
        at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:166)
        at jade.android.RuntimeService$7.run(RuntimeService.java:278)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
        at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:80)
        at jade.core.messaging.MessagingService.boot(MessagingService.java:326)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.bootAllServices(AgentContainerImpl.java:468)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.startNode(AgentContainerImpl.java:408)
        at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:495)
        at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:166)
        at jade.android.RuntimeService$7.run(RuntimeService.java:278)
06-23 01:24:26.441  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: APDescription.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
06-23 01:24:26.441  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
06-23 01:24:26.441  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
06-23 01:24:26.441  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:80)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at jade.domain.ams.writeAPDescription(ams.java:1435)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at jade.domain.ams.setup(ams.java:144)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at jade.core.Agent$ActiveLifeCycle.init(Agent.java:1542)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at jade.core.Agent.run(Agent.java:1488)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
06-23 01:24:26.442  25603-25644/com.jadeandroid.test.jadeandroid W/System.err﹕ ... 8 more
```

[error ends here]

Actually, this is Permission error from Android that prevents app from write file to /system or /data even I added permission of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

What should I do?

I'm guessing it might be a problem of profile, am I right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the file path u try to access or write to?

Comment: @k0sh I don't know. It is internal file of Jade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone needs help on this, you can change path with Profile

for example,

```
Profile p = new ProfileImpl();
p.setParameter(Profile.FILE_DIR, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/jade/");
```

Of course, make sure that add permission in manifest

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ permission too.
```

But it doesn't matter whether you do it or not for executing JADE container

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem, but when I'm trying to implement your solution, I get this error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/jade/MTPs-Main-Container.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)